# How to hide unchecked checkboxes when printing

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am working on creating a contract specification page in Word 2013 with checkboxes so that my boss can click each box that he wants to include in the final printed contract, and hide the ones he doesn't need. I'm completely new to VBA but I know that I need to use it to achieve this. From searching the internet I've used bookmarks and the code below:

```vb
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
 If CheckBox1.Value = False Then
 ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Work1").Range.Font.Hidden = True
 Else
 ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Work1").Range.Font.Hidden = False
 End If
 End Sub
```

But this code seems to hide the checkboxes before I can click them. I would like the checkboxes to stay visible until they print, in case my boss needs to make a change. I also tried using another code, but it also didn't work the way I wanted it to:

```vb
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
  If CheckBox1.Value = False Then
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Work1").Application.Options.PrintHiddenText = False
Else
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Work1").Application.Options.PrintHiddenText = True
End If
End Sub
```

I would also like to make it so there are no gaps where the unused checkboxes would be. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have overcomplicated the issue yesterday. Your only problem was that your checkboxes turn unvisible along with the text. You just need to **bookmark exactly the text you want to hide/show** leaving the checkbox (perceived by Word as a part of the text) outside of the bookmark.

Your code will do this fine, or you can replace it with this:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
Bookmarks("Work1").Range.Font.Hidden = Not CheckBox1
End Sub
```

By the way, if you make Word show paragraph marks (Ctrl + *), you will be able to see hidden text.

Comment: Will the checkbox hide when the document is printed or emailed? Also, the checkbox is not included in the bookmark. I created the bookmarks before I inserted the checkboxes.

Comment: @JordynP, it does not matter what you created first, a bookmark or a checkbox. You most likely added your checkbox to the bookmark after you created the bookmark. Try deleting your bookmark, then select a text you want to hide, and add a bookmark with the same name again.

Comment: I assume you use ActiveX checkboxes. They will be printed unless you print the document via the code you can find in the answer there. http://superuser.com/questions/898762/dont-print-activex-checkbox

And definitely they will be preserved when you email the file unless you use some other code deleting them.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest your macros:

a) save the current document (in the temporary folder if you want)

b) delete all unchecked boxes

c) print the document

d) close the document

e) open the file saved in the point a).

Should take a dozen lines of code or so.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you have an example of how I would do this? I'm a novice. Also, I'm not sure that my boss would like that coding, because he often has to go back and edit the specifications page before the customer agrees to the contract.